# Using COM Apartment STA

Tags: com, sta

After reading most of the threads about this topic, I'm still confused.

If I use a instance of a COM STA DLL from multiple threads in .Net, wouldn't the COM technology serialize the call using a queue?

```
var instance = new 3PartyComStaLib()
```

Multiple threads doing

```
instance.doWork();
```

If true, would this be okay, and the only penalty is that it would be slow?

Comment: The terminology is confused and there isn't actually a call visible in the snippet, but the rough answer is "yes".  This isn't much of a question, is that really all you wanted to know?

Answer (score 3):

COM calls to STA object are going to be serialized provided that you don't violate the rules on your end. In particular, you have to make sure that your code does not pass raw COM pointers across apartment borders.

When your STA code needs to pass the COM pointer to another thread and apartment, you need to marshal the pointer (e.g. using wonderfully named [`CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API) and then unmarshal on the target stream, to give COM the chance to create proxy/stub pairs and set the serialization in question up.